# Visual Studio - How can I automatically close server data connections on build?

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework, server-explorer

Is there a way to automatically close the open server connections in the Server Explorer panel in Visual Studio 2010?

I'm using EF and a contextInitializer which always drops the database when building (testing stuff).

70% of the time I forget to manually close the connection which gives me a "cant delete the DB because its being used" error.

Its a small thing, i know, but its making me mad!

Thanx in advance!
Alex!

Comment: It's driving me mad too. Any clues yet?